# In python np.diff() mean out[n] = a[n+1] - a[n] but i want out[n]=a[n]-a[n-1]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

In numpy:
`np.diff()` is
`out[n] = a[n+1] - a[n]`

but what is the syntax for 
`out[n]= a[n]-a[n-1]`

```
x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 0])
np.diff(x)
```

op- `array([ 1,  2,  3, -7])`

but i want output
      op- `array([-1, -2, -3, 7])`

I have 3D array shape(73,80,97) which is actually WRF model ouput i want rain rate but unable to do:

```
for k in range(1,72):
    rainrate[k,:,:]=rainnc[k,:,:]-rainnc[k-1,:,:]
```

or if i am doing

```
np.diff(rainnc,0) #showing negative value
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand the question, for me it is quite the same... The only difference I see is you want a trailing None value at start...?

Comment: Your edit makes no sense, please give an example of your data and the expected output.

Comment: Your example output does not correspond to the formula you give before that (and in the title). Your example output corresponds to `x[i] - x[i+1]`.

Comment: Furthermore, `out[n]= a[n]-a[n-1]` for n from 1 to len-1 is the exact same thing as out[n]=a[n+1] - a[n] for n from 0 to len-2 but with a trailing undefined balue at index 0 for the first case

Answer (score 0):

Just multiply the result by `-1`:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np

In [2]: x = np.array([1, 2, 4, 7, 0])

In [3]: np.diff(x) * -1
Out[3]: array([-1, -2, -3,  7])
```

Comment: for k in range(1,72):
     rainrate[k,:,:]=rainnc[k,:,:]-rainnc[k-1,:,:]

Comment: @MissPriyaKumari What does that mean?